# SwiftUI: Change a view's transition dynamically after the view is created

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to change a view's transition ***dynamically*** after the view is created. I toggle a State variable `isTransition1` by clicking a button to switch between `transition1` and `transition2` as the below. However, it doesn't work as intended if one of these transitions is opacity. The view to be removed immediately after changing transition always keeps its original transition. Surprisingly, if I change `transition2` to slide, it will work without problem. The view to be removed will use the new transition. Is there any way to make opacity work here?

```
let transition1 = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                                           removal: .move(edge: .leading))

let transition2 = AnyTransition.opacity

struct Wrapper1<Content: View>: View {
  let content: Content

  var body: some View {
    content
  }
}

struct Wrapper2<Content: View>: View {
  let content: Content

  var body: some View {
    content
  }
}

struct TextView: View {
  let count: Int
  let color: Color

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      color
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
               maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

      Text("Count: \(count)")
        .font(.title)
        .offset(y: -200)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var count = 0
  @State private var isTransition1 = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if count % 2 == 0 {
        Wrapper1(content: TextView(count: count, color: Color.green)
          .transition(isTransition1 ? transition1 : transition2))
        } else {
          Wrapper2(content: TextView(count: count, color: Color.red)
            .transition(isTransition1 ? transition1 : transition2))
        }

      HStack(spacing: 100) {
        Button(action: {
          self.isTransition1.toggle()
        }) {
          Text("Toggle Transition").font(.title)
        }

        Button(action: {
          withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) {
            self.count += 1
          }
        }) {
          Text("Increase").font(.title)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Am trying to achieve the same while implementing custom navigation stack with SwiftUI. @appthumb did you manage to find a solution or workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: Hi! Any news about this? I have the same weird behavior...

Comment: Hey, do you have an answer on this issue. I'm trying to solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I correctly understood what effect you tried to achieve, but try to reset view hierarchy (at least this definitely resets transitions, so they don't affect each other):

```
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if count % 2 == 0 {
        Wrapper1(content: TextView(count: count, color: Color.green)
          .transition(isTransition1 ? transition1 : transition2))
        } else {
          Wrapper2(content: TextView(count: count, color: Color.red)
            .transition(isTransition1 ? transition1 : transition2))
        }

      HStack(spacing: 100) {
        Button(action: {
          self.isTransition1.toggle()
        }) {
          Text("Toggle Transition").font(.title)
        }

        Button(action: {
          withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) {
            self.count += 1
          }
        }) {
          Text("Increase").font(.title)
        }
      }
    }.id(isTransition1)     // << here !!
  }
```

Comment: It does reset previous transition to none but I also want to the removed view takes on the new transition while being removed. For example, if the current transition is `transition2` (opacity), I click button `Toggle Transition` to change to `transition1` (move) and then click button `Increase` to switch views. I want the removed view to move to the left of the screen, but using `.id(_:)` seems to only reset the transition to none -- the removed view simply disappears without any transition.

Comment: Another weird side effect of this approach is that the button `Toggle Transition` appears to remain in the pressed state once it is pressed...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently where I wanted to change the transition inbetween states. Nothing seemed to work until I decided to create an intermediate internal state that updates the UI only after it has updated the transition. I am using a view model that is an observable object.

To solve the issue I created an internal state that is a currentValueSubject.
I also made my transition a published Variable so as to update the UI after the transition changes.

I update the internal state, which in turn updates the transition, which then updates the UI before changing the state.

```
    private var internalState: CurrentValueSubject<BookingWizardState, Never> = CurrentValueSubject(.date)
    @Published var state: BookingWizardState
    private let moveForwardTransition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                                                                 removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    private let moveBackwardTransition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                                                                  removal: .move(edge: .trailing))

    @Published var transition: AnyTransition


    func setupSubscriptions() {
    //Set the transition based on the state change
        internalState.map { [weak self] newState in
            guard let self else { return .slide }
            let isForward = self.state.rawValue <= newState.rawValue
            return isForward ? self.moveForwardTransition : self.moveBackwardTransition
        }
        .assign(to: &$transition)
        //Update the external state after a fraction of a second and after the transition has been updated. 
        internalState
            .delay(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: &$state)
    }
```